# both pdftk and qpdf fail at protecting my documents

Tags: pdf, copy-protection, pdftk

From [pdftk man page](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/), I should be able to protect a pdf document from content copy, printing, snapshots with:

```
pdftk 1.pdf output 1.128.pdf owner_pw foopass
```

But it fails, I can do any of them !

I have also tested [qpdf](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/files/qpdf-manual.html#ref.encryption):

```
qpdf --encrypt "" "foopass" 128 --extract=n -- 1.pdf 1.128.pdf
```

With the same failing result.

And also a commercial pdf tool with the same failing result.

I remember I could successfully protect pdf files with pdftk in the past with this command.

I am on debian jessie.

Have I missed something? Other solutions on Linux are welcome, but with 3 sproducts failing, it liiks like I have a problem with my setup.

I don't want to use a user password (confidentiality), just a owner password (protection).

Answer (score 2):

It mostly depends on how compliant the PDF reader is.  Many of the Linux PDF readers don't honor all the restrictions that can be enabled with `pdftk` or `qpdf`.  You should test your resulting PDF files with Adobe Reader in Windows.  You may be thinking what is the point of PDF protection if the protection can be worked-around, and you'd be right there isn't much point to protecting a PDF if you omit the user password.

Answer (score 0):

Note in the pdftk program, owner_pw prevents the file from being edited (burst, join etc.) without entering the owner_pw.  If you want to protect the file from being opened, use user_pw instead

```
pdftk 1.pdf output 1.128.pdf user_pw foopass
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The user shall be able to open the document